# extract object of responseJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I solved a synchronous problem with ajax that way to use deferred function. 
I get as an response now big object with statusResponse etc etc inside.

My JSONP Objects are also successfully stored in responseJSON Object. How Can I extract it or save it in another variable ?

```
var web = new webService();
web.init(app.info);
```

and here the class

```
function webService() {
    this.init = function(app) {
        var d = this.connect(app).done(function(){});
        console.log(d);
    }

    this.connect = function(app) {
        console.log(app);

        return $.ajax({
            url: 'working url',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: What's the problem?  Where are you trying to access the data from?

Comment: What do you expect `console.log(d)` to output?

Comment: Anything that depends on the value returned from AJAX has to be done in the callback function.

Comment: Also, note, you don't have to give the `done()` method a reference to an anonymous function. You could create the callback on your `webService` object...It seems like a lot of people think they have no choice but to use an anonymous function in these scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

`.done()` is going to be called when the data has returned (but through a parameter). So, make sure you add a parameter to your callback function then inspect it for whatever you want out of it.

```
this.connect(app).done(function(mydata){
  // mydata = the response object
  // grab whatever information you want from it here.
});
```